# Why is my query failing upon adding SUM function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The following query executes as expected, giving me the expected output given the fields being queried

```
SELECT 1 as SEQ, TERM_DESC as TERM, PRIMARY_COLLEGE_DESC as COLLEGE, LEVEL_GROUPING_CODE as     LEVEL_CODE, LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC as LEVEL_DESC
FROM SECopy as SE
```

However, when I add the function SUM() on a field, I'm getting the following error regarding TERM_DESC, which isn't even related to ID_COUNT, which the SUM() Function is used on.

```
SELECT 1 as SEQ, TERM_DESC as TERM, PRIMARY_COLLEGE_DESC as COLLEGE, LEVEL_GROUPING_CODE as     LEVEL_CODE, LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC as LEVEL_DESC, SUM(ID_COUNT) as HEADCOUNT
from SECopy as se
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Column 'Student_Enrollment_copy.TERM_DESC' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

Why would it fail only after adding the SUM() function?

Comment: Any field not in an aggregate (like `sum()`) must be in a `GROUP BY`

Comment: I am not sure but i think it is because there is no group by. I will think adding an aggregate function forces the developer to add a group by clause. Can you try doing a group by on the fields?

Comment: AFAIK SQL Server *requires* GROUP BY when using aggregate functions. There are RDBMSs (like MySQL) that skip that requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Alias Name for Table is not needed
2. You Should Use All Columns in Group BY Clause except Aggregate Function

> ```
> SELECT 1 as SEQ, 
> TERM_DESC as TERM, 
> PRIMARY_COLLEGE_DESC as COLLEGE, 
> LEVEL_GROUPING_CODE as     LEVEL_CODE,
> SUM(ID_COUNT) as HEADCOUNT
> from SECopy
> GROUP BY TERM_DESC,PRIMARY_COLLEGE_DESC,LEVEL_GROUPING_CODE
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to stick any of your fields that are in your SELECT statement, but are not being aggregated by a SUM(), AVG(), MIN(), etc... into a GROUP BY clause:

```
SELECT 
    1 AS SEQ,
    TERM_DESC AS TERM,
    PRIMARY_COLLEGE_DESC AS COLLEGE,
    LEVEL_GROUPING_CODE AS LEVEL_CODE,
    LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC AS LEVEL_DESC,
    SUM(ID_COUNT) AS HEADCOUNT
FROM SECopy AS se
GROUP BY 
    TERM_DESC, PRIMARY_COLLECT_DESC,LEVEL_GROUPING_CODE,LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add grouping criteria to your query.

In SQL server (and many other SQL RDBMSs), aggregate functions *require* the definition of grouping columns:

```
select ...., sum(...) ...  -- Fields, expresions and (aggregate) functions
from your_table -- and / or data sources
-- any where conditions
group by ... --- Grouping criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your actual needs, you might be looking for

```
SELECT
  1 as SEQ
  , TERM_DESC as TERM
  , PRIMARY_COLLEGE_DESC as COLLEGE
  , LEVEL_GROUPING_CODE as LEVEL_CODE
  , LEVEL_GROUPING_DESC as LEVEL_DESC
  , (SELECT SUM(ID_COUNT) FROM SECOPY) as HEADCOUNT
from SECopy
```